# First load the whole page, then display it

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

Okey guys, so as the title says, i need some help about how i can create a Javascript and/or jQuery script which will 1st load all the html page elements (like divs etc.) and then display the page,once it is 100% loaded. I need this because right now, during the loading, one of my divs is moved up, and then when the page is loaded it goes into correct position. Cheers!

Comment: This is a possible workaround, but wouldn't you rather have a solution to the problem you're covering up?

Comment: Do you have any code now? Cheers!

Comment: I would recommend double checking the markup and CSS in general instead of doing what you asked. You'll be turning your website into a usability hell by relaying on JS to show the content of the entire website.

Comment: In my opinion this is a problem that doesn't need to be fixed, since it is pretty normal for a lot of pages, and what you are asking may just cover up some other underlying issue with your code, but: how about wrapping your whole page in a div that has `style="visibility: hidden"` and then changing it to visible in the document.ready or onload handler? Or adding a first element that is an absolutely positioned div with z-index, size and position set such that it covers everything else, and then remove that div on document.ready. Or some other variation thereon.

Comment: @nnnnnn, no JS = blank page = bad SEO = bad usability = hell

Comment: @Ben - easily solved by using a piece of inline JS at the start of the page to make it happen rather than hard-coding it in the HTML/CSS, and thus with JS disabled the page will still load the way it is now. But I was just throwing out a few ideas; as I said already I don't really think it is a problem that needs fixing.

Comment: P.S. If the page is already loading slowly enough that users have time to see things moving around as the browser recalculates element positions, hiding everything until it is all loaded is going to make it _feel_ even slower. At the least you'd want some kind of 'loading' message or percentage complete counter or something.

Comment: One more thing: Are you using tables for layout? They are notorious for being slow to render and causing massive reflows (moving stuff around while the page loads). Are you using inline CSS? That could be another cause of the "moving div" issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by initially setting `body`'s css display to none and show it on `document.ready()`.

E.g.

HTML:

```
<body style="display:none">
</body>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").show();
});
```

Comment: If you're going to do this, better to hide it with javascript as well instead of CSS. I believe `display:none` will have some bad side effects in terms of usability and SEO...

Comment: Well, I can't comment it enough, just don't rely on JS to show the entire content of the website.

Comment: @Ben: As long as you hide *and* show with js, what's the difference?

Comment: @WesleyMurch, none. Hiding with CSS and showing with JS (like this answer suggest) is a huge mistake, hiding with JS and showing with JS seems reasonable.

Comment: @Ben, thank you for your previous answer (about CSS checking) You were right!!! There was the problem, thanks !

Comment: @Ben which event would be appropriate for hiding the document before any element is displayed?

Comment: @jSang something quick, simple and non jQuery dependent like this `http://jsfiddle.net/VRs3r/`. That way, if JS is disabled, the page will show like it normally would like Wesley Murch suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could use clientside templates to build your page, for example the excelent [jQuery.template](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) plugin.

Simply don't build the page on the server, but do it on the client instead :)